# SELECT last 13 months name inducing current Month

Tags: mysql

Experts ,

What is best way to get last 13 months name inducing current month. In the table I have records for every month from 2014.

Note : date format is - 2016-01-15 , each month has multiple records in table.

something like below

```
   SELECT MONTHNAME(start_date) as month_name 
   FROM purchase_order_entry_reports  
   WHERE start_date (needs to select last 13 months )
```

Result i'm looking for

```
 November,
 December,
 January,
 February,
 March,
 April,
 May,
 June,
 July,
 August,
 September,
 October,
 November
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct YEAR(start_date), MONTHNAME(start_date) as month_name 
FROM purchase_order_entry_reports     
WHERE start_date BETWEEN now() - interval 13 month
                     AND now()
```

Comment: thanks but had tried that , returns every months to many times as of many records per month ...

Comment: I see ... usually help if you include the things you already try in the question so we don't repeat the same errors :( ... in that case you need include the year and distinct. Check edit

Comment: did the trick just added field name YEAR(start_date) and order BY start_date

Comment: yes I miss that part because add it at last minute.